# Implementing CRC16 in verilog with dynamic data packet length

Tags: verilog, hdl, crc16

Thank you for reading this and for all of your help.  Anyway...I am trying to implement a crc16 with polynomial x^16 + x^12 + x^5 + 1 in verilog.  The problem I have encountered is that I don't get the entire packet of data at one point in time.  I get a 32 bit word at a time and the number of words is dynamic but is at least 4 words and can be as high as 16384 words or higher. The time is not much of an issue because I am running on a 150 MHz clk and the input is coming in at most a 33 MHz clk but may be a 10 MHz.  This does not really affect me because I am first accepting the data via a FIFO.

I have been trying to develop an FSM but have really hit a roadblock.  One idea is for me to wait for all the data and then just input the entire thing as one big data packet; however, this seems really inefficient and I just don't think I need to do this.  Plus it could take up valuable resources.  Another way I was playing with was to input the first word and do the XOR operation.  Then when the input data only has 1 to 2 bits left that are not xored (not sure if that is worded correctly) I would input the next word.  Upon the input I would continue to compute the CRC followed by another input until the last word is imputed into the module.

With this method I would need to implement a counter or a shift register in some fashion.  Anyway, any help would be nice.  This goes into a command parser/packet parser.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CRC calculation doesn't need to be done serially 1-bit at a time. You can essentially "unroll" the calculation to come up with the individual equations for each bit of a parallel CRC generator. With that, you can create a CRC generator that processes 32-bits of input data at a time, matching your datapath width. This should simplify your design as well as make it higher performance (processing each bit serially wouldn't meet your throughput requirements anyway, unless you don't mind holding off incoming data while the hw generates the CRC).